# error : Invalid project-package combination for Tokenizer 2.0.0. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTooltype

Tags: asp.net, powershell, github, github-actions, nuget-package

I have a ASP.NET 4.8 webapplication and want to maintain CICD using github actions workflow. I am trying to add tokenization task for replace the variable as per the environment secrets after build but couldn't able to do that. showing error

```
Run dotnet tool install --global tokenizer --version 2.0.0
C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\428d356c-7a0d-43e1-ae45-124b620e5916\restore.csproj : error NU1212: Invalid project-package combination for Tokenizer 2.0.0. DotnetToolReference project style can only contain references of the DotnetTool type 
The tool package could not be restored.
Tool 'tokenizer' failed to install. This failure may have been caused by:

* You are attempting to install a preview release and did not use the --version option to specify the version.
* A package by this name was found, but it was not a .NET tool.
* The required NuGet feed cannot be accessed, perhaps because of an Internet connection problem.
* You mistyped the name of the tool.

For more reasons, including package naming enforcement, visit https://aka.ms/failure-installing-tool
```

Here is my github workflow file.

```
name: Build-Test
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - dev
env:
    API_URL: ${{ secrets.API_URL }}
jobs:
  Build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Setup MSBuild
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1

    - name: Setup NuGet
      uses: NuGet/setup-nuget@v1.0.5

    - name: Restore NuGet packages
      run: nuget restore adminlte2_Dashboard.sln

    - name: build
      run: |
           mkdir artifacts
           msbuild adminlte2_Dashboard/adminlte2_Dashboard.csproj /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=./artifacts
     
    - name: Install Tokenizer tool
      run: dotnet tool install --global tokenizer --version 2.0.0
      
    - name: Tokenize web.config file
      run: tokenizer --file web.config --tokenization-file tokenization.json --output-file web.config
      
    - name: publish
      run: |
           mkdir artifacts2
           Get-Location
           msbuild adminlte2_Dashboard.sln /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:PublishDir="./artifacts2"
```

I would appreciate any help.